# Alternative to create linear gradient for svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg with linear gradient:

```
 <svg>
            <g clipPath="...">
                <path fill="url(1)") />
            </g>
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="1">
                   ....
                </linearGradient>
                <clipPath id="1">
                    ....
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

Is there another way to fill the `path` tag with a linear gradient or the code inside the `defs` tag every time is required?

Comment: you may try to use the image of a gradient. In this case you may need to clip the image with the path or use it as a pattern.

Comment: @enxaneta, could you give please an example?

Comment: Why would you want another way? What's wrong with the one the SVG specification defines?

Comment: This is an example of a path "filled" with an image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109644/how-to-do-image-clipping-by-using-svg-shapes/56113424#56113424. Now imagine that instead of the image of the dog you have an image of a gradient like this one: https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/vibrant-summer-ombre-background-vector_53876-105765.jpg

Comment: @RobertLongson, my issues is: `id attribute value must be unique` when i add many  times my React Js component that contains the svg. Do you know a solution for that without external library?

Comment: @enxaneta, but how to avoid the issue when i add a component that contains that svh and the ID are the same on the page. How to avoid this?

Comment: add the svg via an object tag or iframe and make the svg a data url. Then it doesn't need to be unique. What's the problem with generating a unique value anyway though? You can generate a guid easily enough.